# Rails HAML how to do a simple loop?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to do a simple HAML loop. That would be like this in ERB view:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
</tr>
 <%= @price. each do |row| %>
<tr>
 <td><%= row.year %></td>
</tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Example just tried this:

```
%table
  %tbody
   %tr
    %th year
    %th price
```

Error:

```
Inconsistent indentation: 3 spaces were used for indentation
```

Comment: Have you tried HAML documentation?

Comment: Yes I have tried: Inconsistent indentation: 3 spaces were used for indentation

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HAML the indentation matters, and it means the code nesting, which allows you not to use closing tags and `end` statements in Ruby code. To make HAML understand your nesting properly, all the indents need to be the same size, 2 spaces for example.

So, your ERB code will look the following:

```
%table
  %tr
    %th
    %th
  - @price. each do |row|
    %tr
      %td= row.year
```

Comment: 1 space.. pr. nested attribute..

Comment: ok, so it is possible to use both 1 and 2 spaces..

Comment: yes, possible to use 1 space, but then you should use everywhere in your HAML code 1-space indents